# Bootstrap - Bottom align menu in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to align the menu text with the bottom of the Bootstrap 3 navbar.

My code is:

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="/assets/img/outa.png" width="120px;"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              <li><a href="/browser/saved/">Saved searches</a></li>
              <li><a href="../index.html">Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="../index.html">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="../index.html">Sign In</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

This centers the menu vertically in the shaded navbar. Is it possible to change this so that the menu lies 4px above the bottom of the shaded navbar area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
#myNavbar {
    position: relative;
}

#myNavbar .nav {
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1819/)

Comment: This solution breaks the function of the collapsed menu.

Comment: This breaks the functionality on smaller devices